# How to capture spark's stderr logs in pyspark local mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'd like to view Spark's `stderr` logs but can't seem to find them. In previous experiences, I launch them from Spark UI under Executors tab, but seems like there's only thread dump in this new environment. Where are the `stdout` and `stderr` logs?

[image]

I am running PySpark 2.4.3 in **local mode** (no YARN / standalone cluster):

```
SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("theAppName")
  .config('spark.driver.memory','1g')
  .master('local[*]')
  .getOrCreate()
```

Python version: 3.6.8
(I'm running in JupyterLab)